# What does "VkImageMemoryBarrier::srcAccessMask = 0" mean?

Tags: vulkan

I just read [Images](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/en/Texture_mapping/Images#:%7E:text=visual%20changes%20yet.-,One,-thing%20to%20note) Vulkan tutorial, and I didn't understand about "[VkImageMemoryBarrier](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkImageMemoryBarrier.html)::srcAccessMask = 0".

code:

```
    barrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
```

and this tutorial say:

> Since the transitionImageLayout function executes a command buffer with only a single command, you could use this implicit synchronization and set srcAccessMask to 0 if you ever needed a VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT dependency in a layout transition.

Q1 : If function have commandbuffer with multi command, then can't use this implicit synchronization?

Q2 : According to the [manual page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkAccessFlagBits.html#:%7E:text=0x00001000%2C%0A%20%20%20%20VK_ACCESS_HOST_READ_BIT%20%3D%200x00002000%2C-,VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT,-%3D%200x00004000%2C%0A%20%20%20%20VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT%20%3D%200x00008000), VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT is 0x00004000. but tutorial use "0". why?

it's "0" mean implicit

it's "VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT" mean  explicit ?

Am I understanding correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0` access mask means "nothing". As in, there is no memory dependency the barrier introduces.

Implicit synchronization means Vulkan does it for you. As the tutorial says:

> One thing to note is that command buffer submission results in implicit `VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT` synchronization

Specifically this is [Host Write Ordering Guarantee](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-submission-host-writes).

Implicit means you don't have to do anything. Any host write to mapped memory is already automatically *visible to* any device access of any `vkQueueSubmit` called after the mapped memory write.

Explicit in this case would mean to submit a barrier with `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT` and `VK_ACCESS_HOST_*_BIT`.

Note the sync guarantees only work one way. So CPU → GPU will be automatic\implicit. But GPU → CPU always need to be explicit (you need a barrier with `dst = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT` to perform memory domain transfer operation).